# I need a copy of the default /etc/apt/sources.list

Tags: 10.10, updates

I upgraded to the RC some time ago and the sources.list is sort of screwed up, meaning I'm getting a lot of 404's when updating. Could someone please post an original sources.list for Maverick?

Comment: Keep in mind that the `XX.archive.ubuntu.com` part should vary by geographic location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you have ;)

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 10.10 _Maverick Meerkat_ - Release i386 (20101007)]/ maverick main restricted
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted
deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates main restricted
deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick universe
deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick universe
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates universe
deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick multiverse
deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick multiverse
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates multiverse
deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security multiverse
```

Make sure the problem is on the sources.list and not in standalone PPAs .list
If you wanna know what exactly is the problem, try to update your packages list on a graphical tool (as Synaptic or Update Manager) not the gnome-terminal. It will show you what adress is wrong.

Answer (score 10):

Since 10.10 is now unsupported, you have to use the server old-releases.ubuntu.com for everything. For example a line like:

```
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted
```

Should change to:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted
```

Here is a complete /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security multiverse
```

After updating your file:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 10.10 _Maverick Meerkat_ - Alpha i386 (20100803.1)]/ maverick main restricted
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick universe
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick multiverse
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security multiverse
```

You might also want to clean out your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory.

Comment: I feel deprived.

Comment: Gah, I shouldn't have deleted that; I didn't see you'd replied. I'm having second thoughts now... I wonder whether that only shows up if you choose to install ubuntu-restricted-extras.

Comment: Let me do a quick experiment...

Comment: Hmm it seems not. I must have missed out from, like the OP, installing well before release (well several months before...)

Comment: I made a fresh install on 2/10/10 with the RC. First of all, the ubuntu-restricted-extras repo was not authenticated, I could solve the problem with this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9934128#post9934128.
Second, the gnome-do ppa was throwing me some 404's, re-added it and everything is fine now.