# How do I install upstart?

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

I use ubuntu 10.04.

I install upstart with failed dependencies.

```
 sam@sam-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install upstart
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
 requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
 distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
 or been moved out of Incoming.
 The following information may help to resolve the situation:

 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   upstart: Depends: libnih-dbus1 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libnih1 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: mountall but it is not going to be installed
 E: Broken packages
 sam@sam-desktop:~$
```

My sources.list:

```
 deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS _Lucid Lynx_ - Release i386 (20110720.1)]/ lucid      main restricted
 # See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
 # newer versions of the distribution.

 deb http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted
 deb-src http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted

 ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
 ## distribution.
 deb http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted
 deb-src http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted

 ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
 ## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
 ## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
 deb http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid universe
 deb-src http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid universe
 deb http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates universe
 deb-src http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates universe

 ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
 ## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
 ## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
 ## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
 ## security team.
 deb http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse
 deb-src http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse
 deb http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates multiverse
 deb-src http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates multiverse

 ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
 ## repository.
 ## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
 ## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
 ## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
 ## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
 ## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
 # deb http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-backports main restricted      universe multiverse
 # deb-src http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-backports main restricted      universe multiverse

 ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
 ## 'partner' repository.
 ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
 ## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
 # deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
 # deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner

 deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted
 deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted
 deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security universe
 deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security universe
 deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security multiverse
 deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security multiverse

 deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates main universe      restricted
 deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates main universe      restricted

 deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted
 deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted
 deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security universe
 deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security universe
 deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security multiverse
 deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security multiverse
```

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `sources.list` file contains a mixture of lucid and maverick sources

for example

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted
```

and

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted
```

I would recommend you replace the contents of sources.list with the recommended list (see linked question below).

**Change all references for "maverick" with "lucid"**

Then reopen your sources.list and change the download server to the nearest country where you are currently based.

finally run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

to ensure your repositories are successfully sync'ed

---

Linked Question:

1. [I need a copy of the default /etc/apt/sources.list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6076/i-need-a-copy-of-the-default-etc-apt-sources-list)

Answer (score 0):

If you come here and your sources are fine but still have the issue.. check this.  It may be a larger problem. http://jeff-traylor.posterous.com/painful-ubuntu-upgrade-from-1104-to-1110

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.